# Parallel LINQ implementation in mono?

Tags: c#, mono, plinq

I was considering trying PLINQ to parallelize some numerical methods which need to be portable.  Does Mono implement Parallel LINQ?  If so, how does performance compare between .NET and mono.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mono trunk as of June 22nd has that code on SVN, hopefully you can try it and help us by taking it out for a spin and filing bug reports.

Comment: Excellent! I will check it out

Answer (score 3):

Apperently, it is planned for [Mono 2.8](http://www.mono-project.com/Release_Notes_Mono_2.8) (Parallel Framework).

Comment: Would it be safe to *assume* mono will be able to run the code eventually with 2.8?

Comment: Yes, I would say so. I would use the method in Jon Skeet's post first tho.

Comment: Thank you.  Now if only there was a date on the release :)

Answer (score 1):

This [blog post](http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2008/Jul-26-1.html) back from 2008 claimed support. Now that was a long time before Parallel Extensions was actually released... I don't know how closely Mono has been tracking the Microsoft API.

Comment: Seems it would be safe to use .NET 3.0 methods for the time being?